# MysqlDataSource Invokes "Connection refused" Exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Here is a part from my program:

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        InitializeData data = new InitializeData();

        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Context ctx = data.getContext();
            MysqlDataSource ds = (MysqlDataSource)ctx.lookup("database");
            con = ds.getConnection();
       ...
```

where

```
public InitializeData() {

    // configuring data source (data base)
    ds = new MysqlDataSource();
    ds.setUser("root");
    ds.setPassword("%");
    ds.setServerName("localhost");
    ds.setPort(3306);

    // configuring jndi
    try {
        Properties env = new Properties();

        try {
            env.load(new FileInputStream(env_props));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to load jndi properties");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        ctx = new InitialContext(env);
        ctx.rebind("database", ds);

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.err.println("Naming Exception");
        System.exit(1);
    } 


}

public Context getContext() {
    return ctx;
}
```

As you can see, I try to connect to MySQL. Actually, MySQL is embedded in my java program.
When I connect via DriverManager (using `con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:mxj://localhost", "root", "");`) everything works. But using a DataSource object as it shown above invokes an exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused: connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:140)
at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:110)
at statistics.DatabaseWorks.main(DatabaseWorks.java:26)
```

Could anybody, please, help me?

---

Some tests viewed that my program attempts to connect to a MySQL server, which is not embedded (see BalusC's answer). If I start the server(not embedded) everything works. So I need a way to say my program to start the local one. For some reason `ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql:mxj://");` doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to connect to a real MySQL server instead of an embedded MySQL server.

I've never tried it, but the following should in theory work:

```
ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql:mxj://localhost");
ds.setUser("root");
ds.setPassword("");
```

So with exactly the same parameters as in your `DriverManager#getConnection()`.

By the way, the `InitializeData` thing is pretty overcomplicated. I'd suggest to simplify this. Since you are creating the datasource manually, you don't need to put it in JNDI scope at all. Just create `ds` and use `ds.getConnection()` directly. The JNDI is only useful if you have delegated the creation of the datasource to some JNDI container like a Java EE application server.

---

**Update** as per the comments: it just look like that `MysqlDataSource` isn't designed for embedded MySQL at all. If all you want is a connection pooled datasource, try [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/). It should work universally since all it needs is the full JDBC URL, username and password, exactly the same as you pass to `DriverManager`.

Comment: I have tried this but these changes provided the connection-refused-exception again.

Comment: Well, I think (agreed with you =) ) that I'm trying to connect to a MySQL server which is not embedded. How can I make my program to use the embedded one?

Comment: That is TRUE! I have started MySQL (not embedded) and everything works!!! SO that it doesn't understand that it needs to start a local server

Comment: If you're using a real MySQL server, you may find this [mini tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358) useful as well.

Comment: Actually, I must use an embedded server